Can't get @rendermode InteractiveAuto to execute code in sample app
In my blazor app, I'm trying to get @rendermode InteractiveAuto to work, so I created a simple sample project by creating a new project and including the sample pages.
I now have button on my home page with an onclick function that is not getting called:
<button @onclick="ChangeAppName">Change App Name</button>

If I use @rendermode InteractiveWebAssembly or @rendermode InteractiveAuto, then I get an error in the debug output that it can't find the home page, even though it is showing it. If I use @rendermode InteractiveServer, then it works, (the AppName changes and the breakpoint is hit) even though I still get the Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET in the browser console.
What is the trick to getting auto to work in the sample app?
And is ERR_CONNECTION_RESET normal and I can ignore it?
I tried this in .Net8 and 9 with the same result.

UPDATE
I'm confused by example 7 on this page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/render-modes?view=aspnetcore-9.0
@page "/render-mode-7"

<SharedMessage @rendermode="InteractiveServer" />
<SharedMessage @rendermode="InteractiveWebAssembly" />

Does this page go in the client or the server project?

To work in Wasm mode, Home must be in the Client project.

@MrCakaShaunCurtis That fixed it. Can you post it as an answer so I can accept it?

To work in WebAssembly the page, in this case Home, must be in the  Client project.

You may need to adjust the namespace to get this to work. In my case, Pages folder is under Components in the server project but not in the client project. So my namespace in the cs file changed from 'namespace BlazorApp1.Components.Pages' to 'namespace BlazorApp1.Client.Pages' instead of 'BlazorApp1.Client.Components.Pages'
